# Unable to run script on headless browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run below code in eclipse :-

```
HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

// open google.com webpage
unitDriver.get("http://google.com");

System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + unitDriver.getTitle());
```

it showing the error:-

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z

Please suggest how can I run the script on headless browser?

Comment: Have you tried 
HtmlUnitDriver a= new HtmlUnitDriver();

a.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

Comment: the error shown.. you are trying to check equality by passing two parameters of char.. but in your provided code it cant not be show..FYI `equalsIgnoreCase` method takes only one string parameter for checking equality.....

Comment: ok thank you. But let me try it will let you know.

Comment: No but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Oh.. you are trying to use `equalsIgnoreCase` from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` class...here you can send two char parameters..

Comment: Can you share that's part of code.. where you check the quality??

Comment: i didn't get the point can you please explain

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class Headless {

 @Test
 public static void testHeadless() {
   
  HtmlUnitDriver a = new HtmlUnitDriver();
   a.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  
 
  // open google.com webpage
  a.get("http://google.com");
 
  System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + a.getTitle());
 
 
 }
}

Comment: there is no problem in your provided code..it runs well...I think problem with you dependencies.. can you tell me what version you are using of  **apache commons lib**..??

Comment: apache commons lib version 3.4

Comment: Just run this code `System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("test","test"));`...and let me know what is the result??

Comment: not able to run this code its showing compilation error

Comment: Still i dint get any answer of this. Please suggest